# 'const auto' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *const '

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

Code in header:

```
extern const char* const foo;
```

Code in source:

```
const auto foo = "bar";
```

Visual studio 2015 producess the following error:

> Error C2040   'foo': 'const auto' differs in levels of indirection from
>   'const char *const '

My embedded compiler (uVision from Keil) has no problem with this code, neither does [Clang (coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6737e5d202049424). My question is, is this a bug in the VS compiler or is there a problem in my code?

Comment: `auto` doesn't deduce cv-qualifiers.

Comment: Related: [Does a declaration using “auto” match an extern declaration that uses a concrete type specifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386010/does-a-declaration-using-auto-match-an-extern-declaration-that-uses-a-concrete)

Comment: @BlackDwarf Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your `auto` is not `const` enough - it's deduced as `const char *` (which is the type of a string literal), and you need `const char * const`. I don't think it's a compiler bug.

I would expect that this code to throw an error with in GCC and clang when compiled with `-pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 0):

The definition shall follow the declaration (omitting extern): `const char* const foo = "bar";`