# extern declaration defined using auto. Legal? Compilers differ

Tags: c++, c++17

Why does this not compile with gcc/msvc? clang is happy and hopefully right.

```
#include <type_traits>
extern const int s1;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(s1),int const>);
auto  const s1 = int{42};
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(s1),int const>);
```

Comment: what compiler version are you using?

Comment: it is reproducible https://godbolt.org/z/RkhHqy @S.M. you are declaring local variables, which are a different beast.

Comment: Thank you for providing a link, @bolov. I tested this on godbolt and should of course have provided a link myself.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386010/does-a-declaration-using-auto-match-an-extern-declaration-that-uses-a-concrete

Comment: Thank you Mark for providing a definitive answer.