# Explicit instantiation of a variable template defined with `auto` keyword

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, auto, variable-templates

If one has a variable template with the type deduced from the initializer by means of `auto` keyword, for example:

```
template <typename T>
auto * p = (T*)nullptr;
```

How to make an instantiation of the variable for a particular type (e.g. to export it from a shared library)?

GCC and Clang way is to replace `auto` with the specific type:

```
template int * p<int>;
```

But it is rejected by MSVC with the error:

```
error C3410: 'p<int>': the type of the explicit instantiation 'int *' does not match the type of the variable template 'auto *'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/66xModTjK

MSVC demands to make the instantiation as:

```
template auto * p<int>;
```

which is in turn rejected by GCC and Clang with some weird messages:

```
error: 'auto' variable template instantiation is not allowed
error: declaration of 'auto* p<int>' has no initializer
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7j3nh7Whx

Which compilers are right here according to the standard?

Comment: "variable template", not "template variable"

Comment: You can do explicit instantiation of variable templates!?

Comment: [temp.explicit]p6: "The declaration in an explicit-instantiation and the declaration produced by the corresponding substitution into the templated function, variable, or class are two declarations of the same entity. [Note 1: These declarations are required to have matching types as specified in 6.6, except as specified in 14." - That's the only pertinent thing the standard has to say about this.

Comment: Note that compilers don't even agree on mixing `auto` and explicit types in redeclarations of plain variables. `extern int* i; auto* i = (int*)nullptr;` works in Clang, but fails to compile in GCC and MSVC.

Comment: Bottom line: don't use `auto` in variable templates.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.explicit#example-2

Comment: @SebastianRedl [Does a declaration using "auto" match an extern declaration that uses a concrete type specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386010/does-a-declaration-using-auto-match-an-extern-declaration-that-uses-a-concrete)